# Qual vai ser a diferença entre o Zend Framework 3 e o Zend Expressive?

Tags: zend

Olá Pessoal estou com essa dúvida, no zend framework 2 apesar dos seus componentes poderem ser baixados isoladamente normalmente eu utilizava um skeleton já pronto disponível no próprio site da zend. No zend framework 3 seguirá o mesmo esquema? Ou você será obrigado a selecionar um por um os componentes(ex: no composer). E qual a diferença para o zend expressive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Skeleton Application do Zend Framework 3

O **Zend Framework 3** conta com um [Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication), que pode ser instalado via Composer:

```
$ composer create-project -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

Durante a instalação, você poderá optar pela `minimal` (instalação padrão) ou selecionar os pacotes que desejar (Ex.: Zend-DB, Zend-Cache, entre outros) e a forma como deseja 'injetar' as configurações em seus arquivos do projeto.

---

### Diferenças entre o Zend-Framework e o Zend-Expressive

O **Zend Framework** é uma coleção de mais de 60 pacotes (incluindo o Expressive) que podem ser instalados via Composer, e funcionam de forma integrada (como um framework "full-stack") ou isoladamente, com o objetivo de facilitar o desenvolvimento de aplicações na arquitetura Model-View-Controller.

De outro lado, o **Zend Expressive** é um micro-framework, concebido para situações em que você não precisa de um framework "completo" e possa ter a flexibilidade para criar a sua própria arquitetura. Os [principais fundamentos](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-expressive/) dele são:

1. Troca de mensagens HTTP em conformidade com a **PSR-7**;
2. A possibilidade de criar camadas de **Middleware** utlizando a PSR-7;
3. Um mecanismo de **Routing** que pode utilizar o Aura.Router, o FastRoute ou o próprio Zend-MVC;
4. Um mecanismo de **Injeção de Dependência e Containers** que pode utilizar o Aura.DI, o Pimple ou o próprio (e excelente) Zend-ServiceManager;
5. Um mecanismo de **Template** que pode utilizar o Plates, o Twig ou o próprio Zend-View;
6. E, por fim, um **Error Handler** para o tratamento de erros.

---

### Skeleton Application do Zend Expressive

O Zend Expressive também possui um **Skeleton Application**, que pode ser instalado via Composer:

```
$ composer create-project zendframework/zend-expressive-skeleton path/to/install
```

Infelizmente não pude publicar mais do que duas referências (links) devido a minha baixa reputação.

De qualquer forma, espero tê-lo ajudado! :)

Comment: Não havia necessidade de se desculpar, pois o principal você já esplanou. A questão dos Middlewares e PSR foi dita.

Comment: Poxa! Obrigado mesmo em explicar! Estava meio nebuloso devido os dois serem lançados praticamente no mesmo tempo isso me confundiu um pouco